# Turn loop into list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I turn this loop:

*(test_list is a list of strings)*

```
reversed_list = []
    for element in test_list:
        reversed_list = [element] + reversed_list
    return reversed_list
```

into a list comprehension in python

(sorry I'm a new programmer and I'm stuck)

Comment: You can't, without iterating over the list in reverse in the first place.

Comment: `test_list[::-1]`

Comment: or, for some more readable, `reversed_list  = list(reversed(test_list))`.

Comment: If it's an actual example of a list comprehension that you are after then using James's variant would be `reversed_list = [item for item in reversed(test_list)]` but all the heavy lifting is being done by `reversed` or `[::-1]` so in reality there's no need for a list comprehension in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use test_list.reverse()

Comment: This does not use a list comprehension, nor explain why a list comprehension is unnecessary.